# Как исключить из Sphinx нерелевантные результаты?

Tags: php, sphinx

Подскажите новичку .
Есть запрос "медицинский администратор" .

Через API он делается так у меня

```
 $sphinx->SetMatchMode( SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2  );

 $result = $sphinx->query('медицинский администратор', '*');
```

Поиск ищет хорошо , но при этом  учитывает слова по отдельности и получается  еще  такие результаты  :

1. ```
    Администратор апарт-отеля
   ```
2. ```
    Администратор в ночь
   ```
3. и т.п словом Администратор

Подскажите, как мне исключить подобные нерелевантные результаты  ?